# Laravel - Accessing model value inside Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have five tables: *requesters*,  *document types*, *protocols*, *flows* and *documents*.

**Relationships**

- *Requester* has many *document types*.
- *Requester* has many *protocols*.
- *Protocol* has many *flows*.
- *Flow* has many *documents*.
- *Document type* has many *documents*.

**Problem**

Select all *protocols* that have the first *flow* (let's say sequence = 1) with *documents* having all *document types* for protocol *requester*.

In other words, select the protocols that doesn't have pendencies, this means protocols with documents inside first flow having all required document types for protocol requester.

**Solution**

I ended up with a solution that actually doesn't work because I can't access **requester_id** value inside protocols `whereHas` Closure:

```
// All document types id's group by requester id's.
$documentTypesByRequester = DocumentType::all()
  ->groupBy('requester_id')
  ->map(function ($documentTypes, $requesterId) {
      return $documentTypes->pluck('id')
             ->toArray();
  })->toArray();
// Defined statically to reduce the complexity of question.
// $documentTypesByRequester = [
//    1 => [1, 2, 3],
//    2 => [4, 5]
// ];
// Here I have to select all protocols that have flows with
// documents having all document types of protocol requester.
$protocols = Protocol::whereHas('flows', function ($flows) use ($documentTypesByRequester) {
    // 
    // *---------------------------------------
    // * THIS DOESN'T WORK BUT IS WHAT I NEED!
    // *---------------------------------------
    // 
    // Access the requester id for current protocol.
    $requesterId = $flows->first()
        ->protocol
        ->requester_id;
    $documentTypesId = $documentTypesByRequester[$requesterId];

    return $flows->where('sequence', 1)
        ->whereHas('documents', function ($documents) use ($documentTypesId) {
            return $documents->whereIn('document_type_id', $documentTypesId);
        }, '=', count($documentTypesId));
})->get();
```

There is some way to access values of model inside this `whereHas` Closure or exists another alternative to help me solve this query?

Comment: Hey, could you also share the code where you don't set `documentTypesByRequester` statically? I want to give this query a try, but with static data it's a bit tricky and I might unnecessarily over-complicate stuff.

Comment: @AndriusRimkus no secret. Updated question.

Comment: Can you post your migrations and relationships?

Comment: Can a flow have multiple documents of the same type (per requester)?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$documentTypes = DocumentType::whereColumn('requester_id', 'protocol.requester_id');
$protocols = Protocol::whereHas('flows', function ($query) use ($documentTypes) {
    $query->where('sequence', 1)
        ->whereHas('documents', function ($query) use ($documentTypes) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('count(distinct document_type_id)'))
                ->whereIn('document_type_id', (clone $documentTypes)->select('id'));
        }, '=', DB::raw('('.(clone $documentTypes)->selectRaw('count(*)')->toSql().')'));
})->get();
```

Comment: Great trick! but this doesn't works because of line `DB::raw('('.(clone $documentTypes)->selectRaw('count(*)')->toSql().')')` that converts to a sql string instead of a *number* that's what the parameter expects...

Comment: Did you try the query?

Comment: Look at Laravel API: `whereHas(string $relation, Closure $callback, string $operator = '>=', int $count = 1)`

Comment: You can still pass a raw expression. Replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and look at the result.

Comment: There's no way to execute this select before and pass his return value to the integer parameter?

Comment: The error message with this approach: `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`

Comment: No, there isn't. Do you get this error when using `->get()` or `->toSql()`?

Comment: Ok, I got the problem. My `DocumentType` model has a global scope that isn't filled executing this expression so I removed it from this query.