# Laravel - Access model attribute dynamically inside whereHas Closure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have the relation: **Role** has many **Users**. Role and user stores a `code` value.

If I want to select all roles that have users with same `code`, how would be this query using `whereHas` clause?

What I tried:

```
$roles = Role::whereHas('users', function ($users) {
    // Obviously doesn't work but it is what I need to access.
    $code = $users->first()
        ->role
        ->code;

    return $users->where('code', $code);
})->get();
```

Comment: Is this to see how it would would using the `whereHas` method, or just to have this working regardless of the method used?

Comment: @thisiskelvin Actually this is a symbolic example to a more complex one that I have to use `whereHas`. So it's required.

Comment: I would like to see the result of this. I think the problem is finding out a way to access the current `role` iteration within `whereHas()` to be able to use within the query.

Comment: @thisiskelvin yeah, agree

Comment: Are you anywhere closer to finding an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Access column value dynamically inside whereHas Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389481/laravel-access-column-value-dynamically-inside-wherehas-closure)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$roles = Role::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->whereColumn('users.code', 'roles.code');
})->get();
```

Comment: If I need to use the `code` value for another operation, like filter a php array, I couldn't use this approach?

Comment: For example: `$code = $query->getColumn('roles.code');`

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can get the `code` from the result: `foreach($roles as $role) { echo $role->code; }`

Comment: You've missed the `$query` in function parameter

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir no, I need the value of `code` inside whereHas Closure.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. What do you want to do with the `code` value in this context?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir the complete problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388136/laravel-accessing-model-value-inside-query-builder